# SQL queries when two or more tables to be joined

Tags: mysql

IMDB database has the following tables

```
actors(id, first_name, last_name, gender)  
directors(id, first_name,last_name)  
directors_genres(director_id, genre, prob)  
movies(id, name,year, rank)  
movies_directors(director_id, movie_id)  
roles(actor_id,movie_id, role)  
movies_genres(movie_id, genre)
```

a) Write a query that lists the female actors who appeared in a movie during the 90s (1990-1999) that was rated higher than 8.5.

b) Write a query that lists all actors who was in a movie rated lower than 3.0 two or more times. List the name of the actor, the movie and each rating, ordered ascending by the actors’ last name then first name.

c) Write a query that lists all actors who have been in two or more movies of different genres. List their name, movie and their respective genres.

My answers:

a)

```
SELECT actors.firstname 

    from ((roles inner join movies on roles.mid=movies.id)
            inner join actors on actors.id=roles.aid) 
    where (movies.year between 1990 and 1999)
            and
          (movies.rank >= 8.5)
```

. is it correct ?

and can anyone help how to approach other queries. Thanks in advance

Comment: *Is it correct?* Well, do you get the correct rows out of your data (which we can't see) to match the criteria? As to the other queries, you should make an effort to write them yourself before asking for help here.

Comment: "Is it correct?".  Why don't you run it and find out???

Answer (score 0):

You forget gender, and higher than 8.5 (not higher than or equals).

```
SELECT actors.firstname 
from roles inner join movies on roles.movie_id = movies.id
        inner join actors on actors.id=roles.aid
where movies.year between 1990 and 1999
        and movies.rank > 8.5
and actors.gender = 'F';
```

P.S. Is this your school work?

Comment: yes , my home work . thanks for pointing it out . How to approach other two queries . Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    first_name, last_name 
FROM actors 
    JOIN
    movies ON actors.id=movies.id
WHERE movies.gender='female'and movies.rank>8.5 AND movies.year
BETWEEN 
    1990-1999
```

**Add role to actors table**

```
actors(id, first_name, last_name, gender,role)
movies(id, name,year, rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
SELECT actors.firstname FROM actors WHERE id IN(
SELECT actors_id FROM roles WHERE movies_id IN(
SELECT id FROM movies WHERE (movies.year BETWEEN 1990 and 1999)
                        and (movies.rank >=8)));
```